# Planning, architecture and implementation of

Tags: word-choice, sentence

Is *Planning, architecture and implementation of* correct English if I want to express that I did

1. the planning
2. planning of the architecture
3. and the implementation of something?

Comment: Normally one would not say "I did the planning of the architecture", but simply say "I did the architecture", unless you mean to imply that you only, eg, laid out the schedule for someone else to do the architecture.

Comment: What does *planning* mean in this context? And *architecture*? And *implementation*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Is this sentence correct english if I want to express, that I did ...

*Is this sentence correct **E**nglish if I want to **express that** I did ...*

[thus not comma before "that"; that's quite rare]

Possible versions:

*I did the planning **— including the  planning of the architecture — as well as** the implementation of something.*

As to why not use "implementing"?

Because not all ing-forms are equally accepted **for names of activities**.

Search for

"participated  in the planning"

and

"participated  in the implementing"

(quote marks are required) at Google **Books**, and come back after that:-)

or:

*I **performed** the general planning, the  planning of the architecture, **and** the implementation of something.*

Comment: Thank you. My question here is: Why do you use "implementation" here and not "implementing" to be consistent with "planning"?

Comment: @Jan see my update.